# No audio in speaker HP spectre x360

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers

After being around 10 years without using Linux I have decided to give it another go to Ubuntu in my new HP Spectre x360. Everything seems to be ok but I have no sound in the speakers, only in the headphones if I connect them. I am a bit rusty in how to debug these kind of things so I do not have much idea at the moment of what I can do. So far I leave the output of pactl list short:

https://gist.github.com/javierguzman/7b7a68f44d90bcaff6094333fa94de38

Version of Ubuntu is 20.04

Comment: This page has a run down of troubleshooting for sound https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/ perhaps give that a look.

Comment: Thanks Noki! Unfortunately I have already tried that without any success.

Comment: Very unusual, are you positive it is not a hardware issue? I myself spent months debugging a sound issue only for it to be my Onkyo amp that was the culprit.

Comment: The speakers work on Windows. Also, I played the other day with hdajackretask and managed to make work the speakers. However, I do not know if I had 2 or 4 speakers working and also I "killed" the headphones and mic in the process :( Perhaps you can tell me your hdajackretask configuration??